# Unique Multi-dimensional associative arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I need to return a unique object based on the key title here is my object.

```
var myObj = [{
    title: 'title one',
    beats: 1
}, {
    title: 'title two',
    beats: 2
}, {
    title: 'title three',
    beats: 3
}, {
    title: 'title one',
    beats: 4
}, {
    title: 'title one',
    beats: 5
}];
```

Now what i really need it to return is.

```
var myObj = [{
    title: 'title one',
    beats: 1
}, {
    title: 'title two',
    beats: 2
}, {
    title: 'title three',
    beats: 3
}];
```

Can someone advise me on the best and quickest way to achieve this would really appreciate some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have tried something before asking for help, but here are two possible solutions.

```
// Solution 1
var newObj = myObj.filter(function(o1, i1) {
    return !myObj.some(function(o2, i2) {
        return (o1.title == o2.title && i2 < i1);
    });
});

// Solution 2
var newObj = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < myObj.length ; i++) {
    var hasAlreadyBeenAdded = false;
    for(var j = 0 ; j < newObj.length ; j++) {
        if(newObj[j].title == myObj[i].title) {
            hasAlreadyBeenAdded = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!hasAlreadyBeenAdded) {
        newObj.push(myObj[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sebastien yes i am building a web app that does a lot of data manipulation and complex array sorting always stumps me thanks for the response worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
var result = [];

for(var i=0;i < myObj.length - 1;i++){
   if(result.length > 0){
      for(var j=0;j < result.length - 1;j++){
         if(result[j]['title'] != myObj[i]['title']){
           result.push(myObj[i]);
         }
      }
   }else{
      result.push(myObj[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to deal with a temporary Javascript object to store the keys like in the following example.

```
var tmp_keys = {};
var filteredObj = [];
for (index in myObj) {
    if (myObj[index].hasOwnProperty('title') && !tmp_keys.hasOwnProperty(myObj[index].title)) {
        tmp_keys[myObj[index].title] = true;
        filteredObj.push(myObj[index]);
    }
}
```

The Output looks as follows

```
[Object { title="title one", beats=1}, Object { title="title two", beats=2}, Object { title="title three", beats=3}]
```